# override admin options template (options.tpl) - prestashop

Tags: overriding, prestashop

i am trying to override the options template (options.tpl) the helper of the themes class and the default admin theme.

[admin-directory]/themes/default/template/controllers/themes/helpers/options/options.tpl

by the way i am trying to do this override using the module i am working on. the problem is that i am not able to find the controller i need to override to give the new path of the new tpl file.

i tried to override it by putting the new tpl file in

modules/[my_module]/views/templates/admin/controllers/themes/helpers/options/options.tpl

do you have any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can override the options.tpl for the admin by, locating 
\admin\themes\default\template\controllers\themes\helpers\options\options.tpl

and copy to (create folders if neccessary)
/override/controllers/admin/templates/helpers/options/options.tpl

goto to Advanced Parameters --> performance --> and check "Recompile templates if the files have been updated" and then clear cache ...

Comment: i totally forgot about this question.. i figured it out an forgot to update it.. thank you and i hope it would help others.